# Modifying a clipboard content to be treated as HTML

Tags: python, html, autohotkey

When I “copy an image” on the web (by highlighting the image and ctrl+C) and then passed it into the text view of the HTML WYSIWYG editor (not the source code editor) the picture is displayed. Even though  I paste in the text editor ( source code editor), the content of the clipboard is understood by the editor as an html code.

For example, if I simply paste `“<img src="someURL" />`in the text editor, it will be added in the source code as `“<p>&lt;img src="someURL" /&gt;</p>”` so this clipboard isn’t understood by the editor as an html code.

So how should I modify the content of my clipboard so that an HTML WYSIWYG editor understand it as an html code even though I am pasting it in the text view (not source code editor)?

---

What I want to do in more details:

when I have the URL of an image stored in my clipboard, I want to be able to add the image to the  HTML WYSIWYG editor without having to switch to the source code editor. So I would like to transform the content of my clipboard (by adding some code before and after the URL) so it is understood as HTML code (just like the example mentioned above) by my HTML WYSIWYG editor.

---

Edit: to better target the answer here is what I try to achieve. When I use shareX to upload a picture, ShareX store automatically this (private) shareable URL in the clipboard. https://drive.google.com/open?id=XXXX 
This code convert it in an embedded format. But I'm still looking for a way to store that as html format.

```
#URL_to_Picture.py 
#
#(xxx=FileID)
#
#You need that kind of URL to be able to embed the picture in an editor:  https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=XXXX
#
#This script does a part of the job by converting Google drive URL into an embedded (and permanent) link:



from jaraco import clipboard
UrlShareX = clipboard.paste_text()
UrlShareX=UrlShareX.replace("https://drive.google.com/file/d/", "")
UrlShareX=UrlShareX.replace("/view?usp=drivesdk", "")
UrlShareX=UrlShareX.replace("/view?usp=sharing", "")
UrlShareX=UrlShareX.replace("https://drive.google.com/open?id=", "")
URL= '<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={}" />'.format(UrlShareX)
clipboard.copy_html(URL)
```

To try on ShareX:

1. You must set the access to Google drive in ShareX menu:
   destination/destination settings/google drive.
2. You must set the ShareX menu: “after upload task” to “copy URL to
   clipboard”

Comment: Thanks for your help! Yes I am on windows, windows 7.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am getting an image link from imgur like `http://imgur.com/SOMEIMAGE` in my clipboard (for the details, the link is sent to my clipboard by ShareX).Then the python script should modify my clipboard (I could start it with a shorcut) so I can paste it directly in the text view of the WYSIWYG editor (I am using TinyMce). I would be great to be able to paste an arbitrary html code but if not img tag would be ok.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me! If you have time sometimes in the future, I will be glad to get some directions from you about how to implement this package. I looked at it but with my limited knowledge in python, I am getting nowhere.

Comment: Looking at your question with fresh eyes I noticed that initially the clipboard holds just a url, not html. With that in mind I updated my answer. Does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. Install [HtmlClipboard](https://gist.github.com/MagTun/154b18e044148fcf637213451901f351) : copy the script, save it as `HtmlClipboard.py` in C:\Python##\Lib\site-packages\
2. Save the script below  as `image_link_as_html.py`(I used some of your code in your question):
3. Create a shorcut for the script in step to (right click on the file `image_link_as_html.py`, and select create a shorcut)
4. Right click on the shorcut, select `Properties`, and and add a keyboard shorcut in Shorcut key.

That's it. When you have an image url in our clipboard, you can just press your keyboard shorcut and you can paste your image directly in the html mode of you editor.

---

image_link_as_html.py (Python34):

```
from tkinter import Tk
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
image_url = root.clipboard_get()

# send <img src="https://image_url" alt="" />  to an "HTML format clipboard"
import HtmlClipboard
HtmlClipboard.PutHtml("<img src=\"http://"+image_url+" \" alt=\"\"/>")
```

---

To address the part about ShareX, you could use this scrip instead:

```
from tkinter import Tk
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
UrlShareX = root.clipboard_get()

# remove everything except the file google ID: this part is not needed 
UrlShareX=UrlShareX.replace("https://drive.google.com/file/d/", "") 
UrlShareX=UrlShareX.replace("/view?usp=drivesdk", "")
UrlShareX=UrlShareX.replace("/view?usp=sharing", "")
UrlShareX=UrlShareX.replace("https://drive.google.com/open?id=", "")
UrlShareX=UrlShareX.replace("/view", "")

# send <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&amp;id=xxx " alt="" />  to an "HTML format clipboard"
import HtmlClipboard
HtmlClipboard.PutHtml("<img src=\"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+UrlShareX+" \" alt=\"\"/>")
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to add the image to the HTML WYSIWYG editor without having to switch to the source code editor

AHK solution: use a hotkey like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>

you have plain text in clipboard: `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/teams/teams-illo-free-sidebar-promo.svg?v=47faa659a05e`
go in WYSIWYG editor and press ctrl+shift+v, it will be pasted in HTML format
HTML format is a clipboard format, so an image will be shown.



what you need is here: `WinClipv2\imgSrc to HTML Format\src in clip.ah2`
I put the code in a repo because there's a library to include:
https://github.com/FuPeiJiang/WinClipv2
READ the README.md