# Pandas dataframe to clipboard: incorrect format for PowerPoint table

Tags: python, pandas, powerpoint, clipboard

Is there a possibility or a workaround for copying a dataframe with pandas to the clipboard and then paste it with the correct format in a table on a PowerPoint slide?
If I copy a dataframe to an excel spreadsheet the formatting works as excpected with DataFrame.to_clipboard() but when I copy it to the PowerPoint table only the selected cell is filled with all the information and the formatting gets lost.
When I copy the table manually from Excel and paste it in a PowerPoint table the formatting is fine. Can you set the Excel formatting directly with DataFrame.to_clipboard()?

Here is an example for copying a dataframe to clipboard:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [1, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.to_clipboard(index=False)
```

Then try to copy it to a table 2x3 in a PowerPoint presentation.
[image]

Comment: If there are no problems with Excel, how about clipboard -> Excel -> PowerPoint?

Comment: because if this step is unnecessary, it would be easier and more comfortable without opening excel

Comment: The pandas documentation indicates that you can use `df.style.to_html()` to capture string formatting, and then use `pyperclip.copy` to send that to the clipboard.

Comment: @thommybee Maybe it will not be more comfortable.

Comment: @Malcom okay but i have no idea what to do with that html string, especially because i only need the values of the dataframe. i need just an array with results, that i want to insert correctly in that powerpoint table. why is it so easy when i copy it from excel to powerpoint..

Comment: @PandaKim maybe i wasn't precise enough. At the moment i have to open the excel file manually and copy paste it into the existing table in powerpoint. i want it to be saved on the clipboard with the right format, so that i only have du ctrl+v the results to the table in powerpoint.

Answer (score 0):

with the help of: [How to copy HTML code to clipboard using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55698762/how-to-copy-html-code-to-clipboard-using-python) 
respectively: https://code.activestate.com/recipes/474121/ 
i condensed the solution to:

```
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate
import win32clipboard # requires pywin32


d = {'col1': [1, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
html_results = tabulate(df.values, tablefmt=`html`)
selection = html_results
# html must be a well-formed Html document that textually contains fragment and its required markers.
html = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\">" \
       "<HTML><HEAD></HEAD><BODY><!--StartFragment-->%s<!--EndFragment--></BODY></HTML>" % html_results
fragment_start = html.index(html_results)
fragment_end = fragment_start + len(html_results)
selection_start = html.index(selection)
selection_end = selection_start + len(selection)
# Replace the Clipboard contents with the given html information.
try:
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard(0)
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    # Join all our bits of information into a string formatted as per the HTML format specs.
    dummy_prefix = "Version:1.0\r\n" "StartHTML:%09d\r\n" "EndHTML:%09d\r\n" "StartFragment:%09d\r\n" \
              "EndFragment:%09d\r\n" "StartSelection:%09d\r\n" "EndSelection:%09d\r\n" % (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    length_prefix = len(dummy_prefix)
    prefix = "Version:1.0\r\n" "StartHTML:%09d\r\n" "EndHTML:%09d\r\n" "StartFragment:%09d\r\n" \
         "EndFragment:%09d\r\n" "StartSelection:%09d\r\n" "EndSelection:%09d\r\n" \
         % (length_prefix, len(html) + length_prefix, fragment_start + length_prefix, fragment_end + length_prefix,
            selection_start + length_prefix, selection_end + length_prefix)
    src = prefix + html
    src = src.encode("UTF-8")
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(win32clipboard.RegisterClipboardFormat("HTML Format"), src)
finally:
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```